# How to unstack pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
job_Id    Company_Name   Min_Salary 
   1           X              50  
   2           X              12  
   3           X              45  
   1           y              63 
   2           y              75  
   3           y              25
```

df_output:

```
job_Id    X      y
  1      50     63   
  2      12     75 
  3      45     25
```

I need to unstack my dataframe as i showed in the above example.
I tried unstack func but i am not able to use properly.

Comment: Use [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot)

Answer (score 0):

`pivot` the dataframe, and if needed, reset the index.

```py
>>> df.pivot('job_Id', 'Company_Name', 'Min_Salary').reset_index()

Company_Name  job_Id   X   y
0                  1  50  63
1                  2  12  75
2                  3  45  25
```

Comment: Is possible not post dupe answers? I think mainly dupes if are many times repeated and easy find by google. Thanks.